# Wine install error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, dpkg

I used the command

```
apt-get install wine-stable
```

to install wine. But i am getting errors as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.0~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

I get the following output when trying to update

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease                 
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Ign:11 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease                  
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:14 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release                    
Ign:15 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease    
Hit:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease             
Hit:18 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 Release      
Get:17 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1,565 B]
Err:17 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu bionic Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFA175A75104960E
E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I am not getting the previous error anymore, however I am still unable to install wine

Comment: Please don't change the question once an issue is resolved. Consider appending the errors you're getting now. `W: Target Packages....` and dependency issues are two different errors. What is the output of `apt-cache policy wine-stable`?

Comment: wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
     3.0.4~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.4~artful 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.3~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.3~artful 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.2~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
     3.0.4~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.4~artful 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.3~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.3~artful 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.2~bionic 500 500 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: You have package conflicts since you have 17.10 and 18.04's repository configured for WINE. Consider deleting/commenting the entry for artful. Moreover the PPAs which produces 404 error doesn't really have release files for bionic (18.04). Consider deleting them too.

Comment: @Kulfy I am a new Ubuntu user. Can you tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable 32-bit arch `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and update
2. If problem persists and apt complains for missing dependencies, `apt install wine-stable-i386` or `wine-stable-amd64` depending on your architecture

Edit: as for those ppas, i would purge them since they are not available for your version

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ppa_name/ppa
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

Comment: Yes I did add the repository. The broken packages error still exist.

Comment: hmm, try `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: No, The error still persists. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Yes this is correct answer and don't forget to `apt update` after you added the new arch

Comment: There seems to be an error even when updating...

Comment: terminal output please?

Comment: **Note:** `ppa-purge` isn't pre-installed.

Comment: install `ppa-purge`

Comment: @LynkzGames the terminal output has been added to the question